# Question closed and answer received afterwards

Tags: discussion, status-completed

After my question was closed, it actually received the answer. I would like to argue that my question was "valid" since someone actually came up with an answer based on my description of the movie:
[French movie - violin, gondola type boat](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19560/french-movie-violin-gondola-type-boat)

The person who answered did not receive his due credit, or points.

Answer (score 4):

I've reopened it to allow the user to post the answer.